# Sort array of objects and return array of specific values from the object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects(product list), and I am implementing the sorting logic to it. In order to make it a single source of truth, I made a id-product map, which looks something like this:

```
const prodsMap = {
  1 : {
    id : 1,
    name : 'abc',
    price : 4
  },
  2 : {
    id : 2,
    name : 'aac',
    price : 3
  }
}
```

Now in order to sort products I am doing this:

```
function sortString(data, propName) {
  return data.sort((obj1, obj2) => {
    const val1 = obj1[propName]
    const val2 = obj2[propName]

    if (val1 < val2) {
      return -1
    }

    if (val1 > val2) {
      return 1
    }

    return 0
  })
}
```

Calling the function like this:

```
const prods = sortString(Object.values(prodsMap), 'name')
```

Everything works fine here, the result of sorting will be an array of objects, in order to get the id's I am using `map` function.

Now the problem is that I've to iterate thrice(first to get object values, second to sort and third time to map id's), I was wondering if there is a better way to get only ID's when the array gets sorted.

Comment: `and third time to map id's` But the `keys` are already the `id`s..? (if they aren't, consider converting to an object structure so that they are)

Comment: @CertainPerformance `sortString` returns array of objects, so keys won't be there anymore.

Comment: btw, `sort` mutates the array.

Comment: @BharatSoni `sortString` returns the sorted `Object.keys(prodsMap)`. But the keys *are* the IDs, not objects. You're not sorting an array of objects, you're sorting an array of keys. (you don't even have an array of objects anywhere here)

Comment: @NinaScholz yep. But `Object.keys` will always returns a new list and that list is passed to sorter.

Comment: @CertainPerformance eh, my bad, I am sending `Object.values` to `sortString`. Updated in question.

Comment: Well, the solution seems simple enough - just call with `Object.keys` instead, like you were doing originally, and the output is an array of IDs, no mapping required :)

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorting can be done 14 different fields(actual products response is quite big and has a lot of fields), like sort on the basis of name, unit price etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could order the keys of the handed over object, to get an array of `id`.

If you need the `ìd` property of the objects, you could map the values of the outer object with `id` property.

```js
const prodsMap = {
  1 : {
    id : 1,
    name : 'abc',
    price : 4
  },
  2 : {
    id : 2,
    name : 'aac',
    price : 3
  }
}

function sortString(data, propName) {
  return Object.keys(data).sort((a, b) => {
    const val1 = data[a][propName];
    const val2 = data[b][propName];

    if (val1 < val2) {
      return -1;
    }

    if (val1 > val2) {
      return 1;
    }

    return 0;
  });
}

const prods = sortString(prodsMap, 'name');

console.log(prods);
```